# Problem with include_once!

Tags: php, include

I have two files. One functions.php and another one that includes_once the function file.

Until now , those files were working parfectly on the server. I tried to run them locally on Apache server using wamp and I get undefined function... This means that the file is not included. Any idea why?

Comment: just to make sure, it is include_once - not includes_once. This is a native PHP function, so if that is not the problem can you paste the error here for us please.

Comment: Do you have any example? Could it be a path issue?

Comment: The second file begins. <?
session_start();
include_once 'functions.php';
?>

Comment: Provided he was writing "includes_once" as part of a sentence where you would say "includes once" and he properly tagged the singular form, I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check the paths. If your server is Linux and your running locally on Windows, the difference between how paths are interpreted is likely to be causing trouble.

Comment: What changes should made...! All the files are in one folder! What's the difference between linux and windows in such case

Comment: Share code and you'll get more specific answers. I can't see what you're doing, so I can't see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: //index.php 
<? session_start(); include_once 'functions.php'; ?>

//function.php
.....
.....

Answer (score 1):

You've misspelled `include_once()`, without the `s`.

Comment: I think he is just trying to make it a verb. What the php file is doing is it 'includes it once'.

Comment: @jwir3: Now that I read the post again, it makes perfect sense.